# Book about a young brother and sister who get sucked into a story book, along with their house, after their parents were killed by a witch

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Book about a family who move into a new house; next door lives a creepy woman. One night a witch comes into their house and kills the parents, and the two children, girl and boy, get sucked into a story book along with their house. They crash in a forest, and a guy from another story book crashes in his plane and comes to stay with them. Somehow, their house gets knocked into an ocean, and I think they find a girl from another story book along the way. After a while they get attacked by pirates and imprisoned. The witch tries to convince the daughter to open a book and read it because it will tell her the truth or something, but she doesn't, and then somehow at the end of the story, the parents get revived and the son and daughter get transported back to their home?

It was a really good book, I just can't for the life of me remember what it was called! If you know that would be great! Thank you. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Someone using another account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, and you can no longer access the account you used to post this question, please follow the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in order to merge your new account with the previous one. This will enable you to edit the question yourself, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is submitted.

Comment: I remember reading this book, but just like you I can't seem to remember what it's called I do remember a bit about how the cover looked like, or at least what I think the cover looked like. The cover was kinda dark but not too dark purple. I also remember that the title of the book was at the top In this supposedly grim writing I think and it had small little skulls near the title and in the center was a picture of this old looking 2 story house and I think it was floating in the water or it was in a sort of swamp-like place I can't remember it that well its been years since I read this story

Comment: @sorry - yours isn't "Pure Dead Magic", is it?  The cover sounds very like it, but the plot doesn't really sound like it.